# Problems returning Property of object as a date object

Tags: javascript, function, date, object, methods

I have an opject called person. what I am trying to do is have the birthday method return a date object for the birthday using external variables see below.  I have tried this several ways to get it to work but no luck. 
best I have gotten is
    alert(person.birthday()); //NaN

```
var person = {
firstName: "John",
mi: "G",
lastName: "Davis",
birthday: function() {
    var x = new Date(bYear, bMonth, bDay);
    return x();
    },    
}
```

I would appreciate some help on this I am new to JavaScript and this is giving me some problems.
    var bYear = 1976;
    var bMonth = "Febuary";
    var bDay = 18;

Comment: Firstly, `x` is not a function, so it should be `return x;`. Secondly, `Febuary` is not a valid month, it's expecting `1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get person's birthday, I suggest you this easy solution:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    bYear: 1976,
    bMonth: 1, //February
    bDay: 18,
    mi: "G",
    lastName: "Davis",
    birthday: function() {
    var x = new Date(this.bYear, this.bMonth, this.bDay);
        return x;
    }
}
```

`bYear`, `bMonth` and `bDay` are properties **attached** to the person so, `birthday` function takes **these three parameters** to return the date object.

Here you have information about Date object: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. Use either [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

The  *new Date(year, month, day)*  function requires the month in array format i.e : '0'=>January, '1'=>February,etc...
Also as previously mentioned no need to create the 'var x'.

```
      var person = {
        firstName: "John",
        mi: "G",
        lastName: "Davis",
        bYear: 1976,
        bMonth: 1, 
        bDay: 18,
        birthday: function() {
              return new Date(bYear, bMonth, bDay);
               },    
    }
person.birthday();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access external variables but you have some bits and pieces wrong in your code like `return x()` and date formatting. Try the following.

```js
var person = {
firstName: "John",
mi: "G",
lastName: "Davis",
birthday: function() {
    var x = new Date(bYear+"/"+bMonth+"/"+bDay);
    return x;
    },    
}
var bYear = "1976";
var bMonth = "February";
var bDay = "18";

console.log(person.birthday());
```

Though i have to say this is not a usual implementation. The personal information should be kept within that object.

Comment: Yes I agree all info should be part of the person object.  The reason for the way I was trying to do this is to allow user input on a form and for the birthday info combine it all and place it as a single Date object into the person object.....

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it thank you for all your help.  The Persons birth month, day and year were not to be included in the Person object. With your suggestions and answers I managed to get a working bit of code below is what I got.

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    mi: "G",
    lastName: "Davis",
    birthday: function() {
        var x = new Date(bYear, bm, bDay);
        return x;        
        }
    }

var bYear = 1976;
var bMonth = "February";
var bDay = 18;

var month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var bm = month.indexOf(bMonth);
```

This let me take the string for the month and get the number value to the function for the birthday method.